# Java robot.getPixelColor if else statement not working

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am new to java and was wondering why my if(){}else{} statement wasn't working properly. Can anyone explain why?
For more context I was trying to make an auto clicker type thing that also moves the mouse to different spots to solve a rudimentary puzzle.

This is what I have so far

```
import java.awt*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Color;

class main {


    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove(1681, 679); 
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        robot.delay(10);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        robot.delay(1000);
        for (int i = 2; i >= 1; i++) {
            robot.delay(3000);
            var color = robot.getPixelColor(1802, 762);
            if (color == Color.white) {
                robot.mouseMove(1700, 679); 
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.delay(10);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.delay(5000);
                robot.mouseMove(1700, 679);
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.delay(100);//click delay
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.mouseMove(1569, 973);
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.delay(100);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.delay(200);
                robot.mouseMove(1142, 729);
                robot.delay(1500);
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.delay(100);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.delay(3000);
                robot.mouseWheel(10);
                robot.mouseMove(391, 822);
                robot.delay(500);
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.delay(100);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            } else {
                robot.mouseMove(1681, 679); 
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.delay(10);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
                robot.delay(10000);
            }

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know the pixel color is "WHITE"? There are different shades of white that can be displayed in an image. Did you display the value of both objects you are comparing?

Comment: yeah I tried using the getPixelColor on it in a diff tab

Answer (score 0):

```
var color = robot.getPixelColor(1802, 762);
```

You should put here Color instead of var

```
Color color = robot.getPixelColor(1802, 762);
```

Comment: it's because you need to specify the data type of variable that you are creating, and in that case Robot::getPixelColor() returns Color.

Comment: Why did you add a comment to your own answer. If you have more information, then update your answer so all the information about the answer is found in one place.

Comment: you're right, my bad. I'm new on this platform. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the var type is used heavily in javascript because it is a dynamic typed language. Java is a statically typed language, so it is not always a good idea to use it in most situation since it reduce readability. The var type has only been introduced in Java 10. you can only use var type in a few situation.

It will work with

var a = "a string"
var b = 2

However it might not work with

var c = new object()

The reason is that the java compiler doesn't know at first what is the type of the value at the right hand side. It would work on Javascript but not in Java since it is a type-safe language.

Thus changing var to the correct type like Color would be wise. Also, I have noticed that your for-loop functionality will go forever. Was that your intention? if not, I'll suggest maybe double check your loop counter or your conditional statement.

Comment: This was a "first draft" thanks for telling me. I will prob change the loop later.